# Split string based on a key and delimiter

Tags: regex, string, plsql, split

I need to split a string based on a key in `PL/SQL`.

```
strCode:=empcode:empname:empcontactno;

strval:=101:John:9345723;
```

I have to write a generic function to split the `strval` based on the `strCode` and populate separate variables such `var_empcode`, `var_empname`,`var_empcontactno` for a bunch of records.

Split based on the delimiter is simple enough, but split based on key and populating corresponding variables is tricky, because the `strCode` is configurable and the function has to be generic to accomodate future changes in the `strCode`.

Kindly let me know if there is an easy way to work this one out.
Thanks.

Comment: Use the Apex utility functions in Oracle.

Answer (score -1):

For this you can use php `explode()` function.

```
<?php 
   $result = explode(':', Your_Array);
?>
```

this gives you an array like below

```
array(
  [0] =>empcode,
  [1] =>empname,
  [2] =>empcontactno
)
```

and you will get these value by using keys.

Comment: Why do yo thing a php answer would be appropriate to Oracle pl/sql question ?

Comment: ok then please tell me how can we do this with sql?